# execute AsyncTask multiple times? [Android]

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When the user clicks the button i call this method which i want to do multiple AsyncTask calls to upload different things. (Some text, Photo, then video). I execute the first method fine (the text) but then i cant start the next call/execute (backgroundTask.execute) because the first one isn't done.

My question:

> How can i call my AsyncTask so i can upload everything at once? (one button click)

I tried having it set up so on the onPostExecute i update a variable and then in this method i have a simple if statement that checks to see if that variable has changed but it obviously hasn't worked.

Should i wait for each one to finish to start the next one or should i do then all at the same time?

Android code:

```
public void UploadEverything(String encodedImage){
    //Gets the email form the user
    SharedPreferences UserCredentials = getSharedPreferences("UserCredentials", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ProductOwnerEmail = UserCredentials.getString("UserEmail", "");


    String method = "ProductDetails";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, ProductOwnerEmail, ProductName, Seller_Category, ProductKeyCode, DescriptionPoint, DescriptionPoint2, DescriptionPoint3);


    if (BackgroundTask.DetailsUploaded.equals("true")) {
        String PhotoMethod = "Photo";
        //BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(PhotoMethod, ProductOwnerEmail, ProductName, encodedImage);
    }


    if(BackgroundTask.PhotoUploaded.equals("true")) {
        String SevenSecVideoMethod = "7secVideo";
        //BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(SevenSecVideoMethod, ProductOwnerEmail, ProductName, String.valueOf(selectedPath));
    }




    Toast.makeText(SellerHomePage.this, "Product has been uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't start the next"?  Is there a crash?  What exactly is stopping you?

Comment: You can not start the same thread again once it finish. You need to create another object of AsyncTask and call execute method on it.

Comment: Why do you want to call AsyncTask multiple times if you can post all things at once?

Comment: @DougStevenson i updated the question and _DhavalPatel_ i have it so when a **method** becomes true it will call a new class and then exectue the code i have in the if statement which is in the **doInBackground**

Comment: @Apurva thats what i am trying to do sir

Comment: create new asynctask . you cant resuse one used async task .

Comment: Is it necessary for you to call all Async sequentially???

Comment: Why do you have commented out code in there? Did those new tasks not work?

Comment: Sagar Nayak: i have it set up so i have all my Try catch blocks in one async task. Nadeem Iqba: yes because i want it to be done with one button. Doug Stevenson: because i already created it a the top and i cant recreate it

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still not clear but what I understood is - you want to upload all your data on a single button click. So here's how you can do that,

If button click event make a call to your asyncTask

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    yourAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

Now it will execute your asyncTask, so in `onPreExecute()` method of your asyncTask you can fetch all the data you want to upload.

```
@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    field1 = //Some Text;
    field2 = //Any Image;
    field3 = //Any Video;
}
```

And now in `doInBackground()` method you can upload all the fields to wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask instances can only be used at once.

You can create new instance and you can use it but you can not use the same instance at multiple time it will gives a run time error.

`execute(Params...)` must be invoked on the UI thread.

-*Do not call* `onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` manually.

So,you can upload all the things in one AsyncTask..

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, if you have such data to upload and sync with server, use a service or a separate thread and handle it in a queue. As you may know `'Volley'` library gives pretty good integration (seamless) with `RequestQueue`, but I have not tried with uploading video. 
Just check [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)